# Showing "unexpected token admin" error although admin is declared

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to do some sequential asynchronous operation. But getting error:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token admin

Although I've declared this variable. Here is my code

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
module.exports = {
   notificationCount: async (change, context) => {
    countRef.collection("notification").doc(context.params.reqID).get().then((requestDoc) => {
      console.log("Request Info " + requestDoc.data().reqUserName)
      return requestDoc.data();
    }).then((requestDocData) => {

      const token = await admin.database().ref("/UserInfo/" + notifiedUserID + "/token").once('value');
      console.log("UserInfo "+token);
      return null;

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Loading failed: ", error);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You have probably figured out by now, but the problem is not actually admin, but rather that you are executing a function with async/await without having stated that it is asynchronous, so you just need to put in async in the function definition like so:

```
.then(async (requestDocData) => {

      const token = await admin.database().ref("/UserInfo/" + notifiedUserID + "/token").once('value');
      console.log("UserInfo "+token);
      return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the issue of the **firebase-admin**, the issues are:

- you are using await without async
- using function expression syntax instead of arrow-callback
- then() should return a value or throw
- use catch preceding to then