# How to create a firebase cloud function that writes data to every 'user' node in firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am attempting to write a firebase function that creates new data nodes for every user in the database, but i just can't seem to get it to work.

Database structure:

[image]

I wish to add additional days to the TimeSlots node, through this function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var database = admin.database();

exports.addTimeNode = functions.database.ref('/message/{id}').onCreate((snapshot, context) =>
    {
        var root = firebase.database().ref();
        var db = root.child('Users').child('Barbers');
        db.once('value', function(snapshot)
            {
                snapshot.forEach(function(data)
                    {
                        //var reqStatus = data.val().request_status;
                        var uid = data.key;
                        root.child('User').child(uid).child(TimeSlots).once('value', function(userSnapshot)
                            {
                                var now = new Date().toDateString();
                                database.ref('/Users/Barbers/' + uid + '/TimeSlots/'+ now +'/9am').set({
                                    availability: 'Available',
                                    id: '01',
                                    time: '09:00 AM'
                                });
                                database.ref('/Users/Barbers/' + uid + '/TimeSlots/'+ now +'/9:30am').set({
                                    availability: 'Available',
                                    id: '02',
                                    time: '09:30 AM'
                                });
                        ...
```

Comment: The time is going to be constant?? Or you will be getting the time from somewhere else

Comment: Thing is you have time `9:00` at one place and `9:30` at other so that is confusing me a bit. You want to add 30 minutes from previous node?

Comment: The times are irrelevant, I just want to know how i can add the nodes for all the child User ID's of the 'Barbers' node, through the function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this way:
By the way I am not a big fan of using `snapshot.key` instead I add the value of UID in  the node itself with a child node named as `id` and it would stay below firstName node in your case. Won't take long for you too adjust your code to add ID there as well along with adding the first name.

```
const allBarbersSnapshot = await admin.database().ref(`/users/barbers/`).once('value').then(function (snapBarbers: any) {
  snapBarbers.forEach((eachBarber: any) => {
    const currentBarberId = eachBarber.val().id 
    
    admin.database().ref(`/users/barbers//${currentBarberId}/TimeSlots/${now}/${yourTimeVariableHere}`).update({ "availability": 'Available', "id": 1, "time": yourTimeVariableHere })
                
  });
  //Anything after above stuff is done goes here !!!
})
```

If you have any questions, drop a comment below ;)

**PS: All the above code goes inside your Cloud Function**

Comment: When I attempt to upload the code to firebase, I keep getting the following error message: "error  Parsing error: Unexpected token admin"

Comment: @MichaelHanson [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59226325/13130697) might help for it :)